# Unable to verify my smart contract on etherscan. Help!

Tags: solidity, remix

I have successfully deployed my erc20 token contract, and here is the address `0x8a37E2eDfdb1557C33B3063c3888E260ce3fc35b`, and also went to abi.hashhex.org to convert my ABI code to get my constructor argument to hex: `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001200000000000000000000000000000000000000001fe86896aa2af25973000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b566f6c74726578476f6c6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000035658470000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.`

Still having an error while verifying my contract on **etherscan**, someone please help me.

Comment: it is not possible to help without any information on what you deployed, and how you deployed it.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say what exactly the problem is with the given info.
But if you reffered to other smart contracts in the contract you want to verify.
e.g "contract StableCoin **is** ERC20 {...}". Then you'd need to flatten the contract.

I believe in remix you'd have to right-click the contract and select "flatten".
It will then generate a contractName_flatten.sol file wich you can then use to verify on **etherscan**.

it's bin a while sinse i did that though.
I'd strongly suggest learning how to verify with hardhat, it's way less of a hasstle.

[docs flatten smart contract in Remix](https://docs.xdc.community/get-details/smart-contract-details/flattening-smart-contracts/flattening-smart-contracts-with-remix)